# Add HyperLink *in Table* With Word JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, office365api

What I'm trying to do is programmatically add a row in a Word table using WordApi 1.3, and populate the row with a **hyperlink** instead of plain text (which apparently is only doable though the "Range" object)

e.g. I am able to add a Hyperlink OUTSIDE a table like this:

```
range.insertHtml("<a href='" + data.DocumentUrl + "'>" + data.Code + "</a>", Word.InsertLocation.end);
```

and I'm able to add a new row to a table like this:

```
tables.items[i].addRows('End', 1, [["a", "b"]]);
```

but if I try to add the hyperlinks to the table like this:

```
tables.items[i].addRows('End', 1, [["<a href='" + data.DocumentUrl + "'>" + data.Code + "</a>", "<a href='" + data.DocumentUrl + "'>" + data.Code + "</a>"]]);
```

it simply displays the HTML code as text instead of as a Hyperlink!

Has anyone managed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to do it by following these steps:

- Programmatically insert a new row with specific keyword placeholders
- Get the table range
- Search for one of the keywords
- Select the first (range) result
- (Finally) insert the HTML  tags

Phew!